# C - Warning for using string format specifier even though I declared char array

Tags: c

The code below runs without errors but a warning is generated about using the string format specifier.

```
    char myname[25];
    int aage;
    printf("\nWhat's your name?");
    scanf("%s", &myname);

    printf("\nHow old are you?");
    scanf("%d", &aage);

    printf("\nHello %s, how are you", myname);
    printf("\nYou are %d years old", aage);
```

```
HelloWorld.c:64:17: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[25]' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%s", &myname);
           ~~   ^~~~~~~
```

Why is this warning generated when I declared `myname` as a char array?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &myname);` ==> `scanf("%24s", myname);` The difference is particularly important when `char myname[25]` is a function argument. Then it's an error.

Comment: `myname` is a `char *`. `&myname` is a `char (*)[25]`

Comment: You may want to get into the habit of using longer default buffers like `255` or even `1024` as people do have [long names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Jacob_Jingleheimer_Schmidt).

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` specifier wants a `char*`, ie a pointer to a single `char` (well, in actuality, to the 1st char of a `char[]` array). But you are passing in a `char (*)[25]` instead, ie a pointer to a `char[]` array. They are technically not the same type, hence the warning.

But, in this particular example, it "works" at runtime without a problem because `%s` will end up receiving the same memory address whether you pass in `&myname` or just `myname` (aka `&myname[0]`), as an array *decays* into a pointer to its first element and the first element is guaranteed to have the same memory address as the array itself.

But, to keep the compiler happy and the code legal, you should pass in what `%s` actually wants, eg

`scanf("%24s", myname);`

Or

`scanf("%24s", &myname[0]);`

Comment: I'm not convinced by the text from "But in this case…" onwards.  The first part I agree with.

Comment: It may "end up receiving the same memory address", but it's a pointer of a different type.  It's likely to "work", but the behavior is undefined.